# SSRS 2008 R2 Forms Authentication - Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to verify the username and password from the Local Database not from Reporting Server database. I have configured Reporting Server and Manager in  SSRS 2008 R2.

The Report Server is able to Login with the username and password from the Local Database, but the Report Manager it is showing the Error Message as "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser".

How can i resolve this issue in Windows Server 2008

Edit:

Edit:

Below is the procedure what i have followed and got the above error message:
Step 1: Installed the SSRS samples from the location http://msftrsprodsamples.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=SS2008R2!Security%20Extension%20Sample

Step 2: Modified the RsReportServer.config

```
<Authentication>
<AuthenticationTypes>
<Custom/>
</AuthenticationTypes>
<EnableAuthPersistence>true</EnableAuthPersistence>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>Off</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionLevel>
<RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>Proxy</RSWindowsExtendedProtectionScenario>
</Authentication> 

<Security>
<Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.Authorization, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity">
<Configuration>
<AdminConfiguration>
<UserName>username</UserName>
</AdminConfiguration>
</Configuration>
</Extension>
</Security>
<Authentication>
<Extension Name="Forms" Type="Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity.AuthenticationExtension, Microsoft.Samples.ReportingServices.CustomSecurity"/>
</Authentication> 

<UI>
<CustomAuthenticationUI>
<loginUrl>/Pages/UILogon.aspx</loginUrl>
<UseSSL>True</UseSSL>
</CustomAuthenticationUI>
<ReportServerUrl>http://`localhost`/ReportServer</ReportServerUrl>
</UI>
```

Step 3: Modified the RSSrvPolicy.config and RSMgrPolicy.config
PermissionSetName="FullTrust" for all codegroups

Step 4:Web.config for Report Server and Report Manager

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
   <forms loginUrl="logon.aspx" name="sqlAuthCookie" timeout="60"
   path="/"></forms>
  </authentication>
  <identity impersonate="false" />

<authorization>
<deny users="?"/>
</authorization>
```

Added two Keys in appsetting block

```
<add key="ReportServer" value="name"/>
<add key="ReportServerInstance" value="instance name"/>
```

Step 5: 
Connecting to the local Database in SSMS with the login table

Step 6: 
http://`localhost`/ReportServer
I am able to login to the database for the Report Server
by providing the valid credentials else it is showing the "Invalid username/password" for wrong credentials

Step 7:
http://`localhost`/Reports
it is redirecting to the uilogon page and asking for the credentials
but the error message "Authorization ticket not received by LogonUser" is showing for Logon button click every time.

Comment: It would help if you could provide more information about what you HAVE done so far; setting up forms auth for SSRS is a somewhat involved process, and without knowing what you have already done, it'll be difficult to guess what your actual problem is.

Comment: i have updated the steps i have followed

Comment: I have same problem. Were you able to solve it?